# php base64 encode appears unexpected character

Tags: php, base64, decode, encode

I have a xml string in php look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PayPlatRequestParameter><REQUEST_HEADER>......
```

And I convert it to base64 form by

```
base64_encode()
```

However, the client say after decoding he found my xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PayPlatRequestParameter?<REQUEST_HEADER>.......
```

so return a error code to me.

I have already try use iconv to convert my xml str from utf-16 to utf-8, set notepad++'s encoding to utf-8 without bom.
but it's cant help.
Cant ask the client to change his code.

Comment: what language is the client decoding it in? php?

Comment: the client is using java to decode

Comment: Why are you converting an XML to it's base64 version and then sending it to the client for the client to decode it back?

Comment: that's the requirement... he say this is security..

Comment: btw i found that it should be my php document problem, i created a new form and send the base64 string directly without curl and it's work

Comment: ok, i found that client change my "+" to "/" and make this error
but how can i slove this without ask him to change his code

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved my question.

that's not xml or base64 question but curl....

it seems con't put it on a string variable, i put it on a array map and the problem sloved